# Redirect secondary network interface traffic along with port forwarding to tun0 (OpenVPN) using iptables

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, openvpn, vps

I have a NAS server which I should do port forwarding for it in order to make its services accessible from internet. However my ISP is blocking ports, so I've managed to buy myself a cheap Ubuntu VPS to run an OpenVPN server there and then somehow redirect the whole NAS traffic and the required ports to there.

My setup is as the following:

```
                                        +--------------------------------+
                                        |            Raspi               |
                      (192.168.0.101/24)|                                |(192.168.1.1/24)
 (192.168.0.1/24) AP<>=================={wlan0                       eth0}================<>NAS (192.168.1.102/24)
                                        |   \                        /   |
                                        |    +----------------------+    |
                                        |    |     iptables and     |    |
                                        |    |    routing engine    |    |
                                        |    +-----------+----------+    |
                                        |                |               |
                                        |             {tun0}             |
                                        |            10.8.0.6            |
                                        +--------------------------------+
```

The VPS side is configured correctly I guess, as I am able to SSH into my Raspberry Pi using my VPS IP. That's what I've done there in order to make it work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d A.B.C.D -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.6:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.6 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

My OpenVPN server config:

```
port X
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

I have also done:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and put `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` in `/etc/default/ufw` and also added

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

to

```
/etc/ufw/before.rules
```

OpenVPN client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote A.B.C.D X
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3

<ca>
XXX
</ca>
<cert>
YYY
</cert>
<key>
ZZZ
</key>
```

How do I redirect eth0 traffic to tun0 and forward ports Y and Z through the tunnel?

I just know that for the other ports I should reconfigure my VPS accordingly as I did for port 22.

Comment: If you've found a solution that answers your question, post it as a separate answer (rather than adding it to your question) and then choose your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to redirect the traffic on my Raspi with the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

When I traceroute out of my NAS it goes through the tunnel. Now I only need to forward ports in this tunnel.

**UPDATE (solving the whole project):**

I finally found the correct port forwarding commands after hours of searching. I've ran the following commands on my Raspi:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i tun0 -d 10.8.0.6 --dport <port> -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.102:<port>
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -i tun0 -d 192.168.1.102 --dport <port> -j ACCEPT
```

And also these commands on my VPS as I've done at first for port 22 at the beginning of this thread:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 217.160.14.45 -p tcp --dport <port> -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.6:<port>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.6 -p tcp --dport <port> -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

So now I've bypassed the firewall of my ISP and I am able to access my NAS and its services using port forwarding on the VPS side. You can use this as a tutorial :)